# Excel Chart with data points not in chronological order

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Say you have total monthly spend for 36 months and you want to display it in a bar graph to show all the spend for the 3 Januarys, then all the spend for the 3 Februarys, etc.  When I sort my data that way, and then put it in a chart, it automatically displays it in chronological order, no matter how I have it sorted.  I want a view of month-over-month to identify seasonal trends, so seeing the spend with the same month of each year grouped together would be ideal.  I can't get that to display.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We need a little more information about how your data is laid out and how are your dates formatted. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 10, version 14.0.6129.5000 (32-bit).  My data is very basic.  I have the year in one column as 10-2012 and a dollar amount in the next column as $5,000, for example.  I did try using the Month function, @Riet.  It did returnt he correct numerical month but I need a bar chart, not a scatter graph.

Comment: I think if figured it out.  I put the months of the year across Row 1 from B1 to M1 with no year reference, and the Years in Column A, then populate the dollar amounts for each month/year in B2 to M4, it works.  Separating the month and year into different cells seems to be the key.

Comment: Glad to hear. You can answer your own question. Just use the area below to describe how you resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

You might try excel's `month()` formula. Putting this in a column as the x axis and then scatter plotting it should work.

For example, if the dates are a1:a12, then I would put `=month(a1)` in column b, with the data in column c.

Comment: `="m" & text(DateColumn,"MMYY")`